# Mahout random forest example, command line parameter for data not recognized

Tags: hadoop, mahout, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

The command:

```
hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47/lib/mahout/mahout-examples-0.8-cdh5.0.0-job.jar org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.BuildForest –d advert-train.csv –ds advert-info –t 100 -o advert-model
```

Generates the error:

```
org.apache.commons.cli2.OptionException: Unexpected –d while processing Options
```

That doesn't seem possible. I looked at the source code and -d is a required option.

---

hadoop version

returns

```
Hadoop 2.3.0-cdh5.0.0
```

The files advert-train.csv and advert-info both exist in my default HDFS directory /users/cloudera

Answer (score 1):

A detailed instruction to run the random forest in mahout can be found here:
https://mahout.apache.org/users/classification/partial-implementation.html

I was able to run this example in Cloudera CDH 5.0 with no problem. I think the problem maybe due to the configuration or the fact that you need to specify the other parameters also. I just used the mahout command in Cloudera for running the example. In your case the command would be:

```
mahout org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.BuildForest 
-Dmapred.max.split.size=1874231 –d advert-train.csv –ds advert-info 
-sl 5 -p –t 100 -o advert-model
```

in which,

-Dmapred.max.split.size should specify Hadoop the max. size of each partition which should be around 1/10 of size of your dataset

-sl is used to specify the number of variables randomly selected

-p tells mahout to use partial implementation

The rest of variables should be fine.